# sed remove characters from new line

Tags: sed

After some processing, I have my input file like below.

**file1.txt**

```
12345|john|student
43321|jack|professor

78965|alex|lecturer
```

I need to process the above file further and so I need a line breaker at the end of the line too. Currently, I can accomplish it as below.

```
sed 's/$/|/' file1.txt
```

The above command results in the output as,

```
12345|john|student|
43321|jack|professor|
|
78965|alex|lecturer|
```

As we can see, the `|` is appended to blank lines too. When I tried to remove the `|` character again from blank lines using below command,

```
sed 's/|//g' file1.txt
```

The `|` character is getting deleted everywhere. How can I delete only the `|` in blank lines? I need to keep the blank line also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your original, you can add `|` to lines that is not blank:

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^$/!s/$/|/' file
```

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/$/|/ if length' file
```

If you want to remove `|` from lines that is blank (in second version):

```
perl -lpe 's/\|// if length == 1'
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know a perl solution. :) I believe perl solutions are more elegant than sed solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it using the below command.

```
sed 's/^|//' file1.txt
```

Basically, I check only the first character using `^` and then if it is `|`, I am deleting it.

Comment: You should solve the original problem with `sed '/./{s/$/|/}'`

Comment: @1_CR, my thought too, but I had `s/.$/&|/`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/../!d;a\ ' file
```

This would serve close to the same purpose as the one below; it would delete any line not containing 2 or more characters, and appending a blank to all of the rest.

This gives me a file kind of like your issue:

```
printf '12345|john|student\n|\n|\n|\n%.0b' `seq 1 10` >|./file1.txt
```

It looks like this:

```
12345|john|student
|
|
|
```

But repeated 10 times.

Then this:

```
sed -n '/[^|].*/s//&|\n/p' ./file1.txt
```

Gives me:

```
12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|

12345|john|student|
```

Sorry it took me a little while to do it right; I need to stop writing these answers on my phone...

Answer (score 2):

Only append a | to a line with at least one character:

```
sed 's/\(.\)$/\1|/' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i~ -re 's/^\|$//' file
```

Searches `^` begin of line a pipe `\|` and end of line `$`. `//` deletes the character. Edit file in place with `-i~`  and create a backup `file~`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the command in question, you can remove the option `g` (recursive) and add the hat character `^` before the pipe to check only the first character:

```
sed 's/^|//' file1.txt
```